# Stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC For Each loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to work in my index view of one model, let's call it Table1. In Table1 there is an ID that links to another table/model, Table2. I want to display text in my index view for Table1 instead of the ID for Table2, however, Table2's main information is made up of two IDS from other tables as well Table3, and Table4, so I need to get the text from Table3 and Table 4 where the actual descriptions are.

Is the only way to do this is by way of a stored procedure? I was thinking yes. BUT, I need it for my for each on my loop on my table. So if the page initially contains the ID for Table2, can I pass it to a partial view and manipulate the table contents?

So what I'm thinking is this :

```
<table>
foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
  @RenderPage("_PartialView.cshtml")
  <td>@item.Cotent</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Basically my question boils down to, will the foreach loop on the main view cause the partial view to iterate and thus display multiple records?

UPDATE: So what I tried did not work. I'm going to try to explain my question better. So my first model, which is the view I'm working in, let's call it **Restaurant**, contains the ID for my second model, let's call it **Taco**. My **Taco** model is has no real string description, merely IDs from my two other models, let's say **Lettuce**, and also **Tomato**. I need to access the description in both **Lettuce** and **Tomato** to display them all the way back in my **Restaurant** view simply in a table, just in one `<td></td>` as an item in the table. I'm not sure how to go about implementing a way to do this. On my Edit view as well, I've created a dropdown menu that uses the description from **Lettuce** and **Tomato** and uses the ID from the **Taco** table to make up the Taco object in the dropdown.

Comment: Sounds like the model you are trying to display involves information on more than one of the tables?  Create a view model which has exactly what you need and send that to the view.

Comment: How do I do this? Can you link an example?

Comment: I'll put together a .net fiddle for you.

Comment: Here is a really basic fiddle, https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Rnuk5.  The idea is that you create a view model which has exactly the info you want to display.  In the controller you do whatever you need to get the info, whether that be database calls or whatever.  Load all of that info into the view model and return it to the view.

Comment: You can pass a model down to your Partial View, even in a loop. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all to answer your above question, will the foreach loop on the main view cause the partial view to iterate and thus display multiple records?

yes, it will iterate the partial view for the each content as per your table. Additionally you can also pass a data to the @RenderPage() and access that using the page property

Ex:

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_PartialView.cshtml", new { User = Model })

@foreach (var user in Page.User)
{
<text>
@user.UserName   @user.UserPassword <br />
</text>
}
```

Official definition : Renders the content of one page within another page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.renderpage(v=vs.99).aspx

Hope above information was useful, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can add an additional parameter, and switch to a `RenderPartial` call to pass another ID into your partial view.

```
<table>
   @foreach (var item in Model) {
   <tr>
       @Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView.cshtml", new { Table2ID = item.Table2ID })
      <td>@item.Content</td>
   </tr>
   }
</table>
```

Hope this helps!